# Django Rest Framework custom permission validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom ViewSet that makes composited queries and updates to the database. I want to establish different levels of permissions, so I can authorize some users to send **GET** method on the view, and some other users to be allowed to request **POST** and **PUT** methods.

[In the documentation I have found](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/), all permissions are considered global to the class view, so I don't know how to apply some permissions to the `list` method, and some different permissions to the `create` and `update` methods of the ViewSet.

This is the main code of the ViewSet:

```
class ReservationCompositionViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request, pk):
            reservation = models.Reservation.objects.filter(booking=pk).order_by('timestamp').last()
            if reservation == None:
                raise CustomValidation(_('There is not such Reservation: {}'.format(pk)), 'booking', status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            result_set = serializers.ReservationSerializer(reservation).data

            result_set['pax'] = self.get_reservation_people(reservation)
            result_set['itinerary'] = self.get_reservation_composition(reservation)

            return Response(result_set)
    ...

    def create(self, request):
        reservation_data = request.data
        user = request.user

        reservation = models.Reservation()
        reservation.booking = reservation_data['booking']
        reservation.agency = models.Agency.objects.get(id=reservation_data['agency'])
        reservation.comment = reservation_data.pop('comment', None)
        reservation.status = reservation_data.pop('status', 'UNCONFIRMED')
        if reservation.status == None:
            reservation.status = 'UNCONFIRMED'
        reservation.arrival_date = reservation_data['arrival_date']
        reservation.departure_date = reservation_data['departure_date']
        reservation.confirmation = reservation_data.pop('confirmation', None)
        reservation.is_invoiced = reservation_data['is_invoiced']
        reservation.user = user

        reservation.save()

        reservation_to_return = serializers.ReservationSerializer(reservation).data
        reservation_to_return['pax'] = self.save_reservation_people(reservation, reservation_data.pop('pax'))
        reservation_to_return['itinerary'] = self.save_reservation_components(reservation, reservation_data.pop('itinerary'))

        return Response(reservation_to_return)

    def update(self, request, pk):
        reservation_data = request.data
        user = request.user

        reservation = self.save_reservation(reservation_data, user, pk)

        reservation_to_return = serializers.ReservationSerializer(reservation).data
        reservation_to_return['pax'] = self.save_reservation_people(reservation, reservation_data.pop('pax'))
        reservation_to_return['itinerary'] = self.save_reservation_components(reservation, reservation_data.pop('itinerary'))

        return Response(reservation_to_return)
        ...
```

I want to validate user has `can_view` permission when method `list()` is called, and `can_edit` permission when `create()` or `update()` methods are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `list()`, `create()` and `update()` methods of the viewset are [mapped](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) to corresponding HTTP methods by the router.

You could thus create a custom permission that inspects the type of HTTP method to determine the action that is taking place.

For example:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

class ReservationCompositionPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return request.user.has_perm('can_view')
        elif request.method in ('POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'):
            return request.user.has_perm('can_edit')
        return False
```

And specify that on the viewset:

```
class ReservationCompositionViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (ReservationCompositionPermission, )
```